# Error when extracting Json data

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary

I've been extracting data from a local .json file and have changed the code to extract the data remotely, as below

```
        GetRemoteData.getDataFromServer { (svrData) -> Void in
            let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(svrData, options: nil, error: nil) as! NSDictionary

            for item in jsonDict {
                var obj = item as NSDictionary
                for (key, value) in obj {
                    var str = key as! String
                    if (str == "Name")
                    {
                        var desc = value as! String
                        self.ctgNames.addObject(desc)
                    }
                    else if (str == "Code")
                    {
                        var code = value as! String
                        self.ctgCodes.addObject(code)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

When I was extracting locally so that svrData was created using JSONObectWithData() it worked fine but now I get an error when declaring obj, '(key: AnyObject, value: AnyObject) is not convertible to NSDictionary'

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `jsonDict` is an `NSDictionary`.

When you iterate over a dictionary, you get a tuple containing `(key, value)`.  In this line of code:

```
var obj = item as NSDictionary
```

you are attempting to cast a `(key, value)` tuple to an `NSDictionary` which is what is producing the error.